# Use if/else logic in tensorflow to either add an element to one tensor or another

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I am building a custom loss function that needs to know whether the truth and the prediction have N pixels above a threshold. This is because the logic breaks if I supply an np.where() array which is empty. I can get around this issue by using try/else to return a 'flagged constant' in the case that the function fails on the empty set, but I'd like to do something different. Here is my current method.

```
def some_loss(cutoff=20, min_pix=10):
    def gen_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        trues = tf.map_fn(fn = lambda x: x, elems = y_true)
        preds = tf.map_fn(fn = lambda x: x, elems = y_pred)
        for idx in tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[0]):
            # binarize both by cutoff
            true = y_true[idx]
            pred = y_pred[idx]
            true = tf.where(true < cutoff, 0.0, 1.0)
            pred = tf.where(pred < cutoff, 0.0, 1.0)
            # now I sum each to get the number of pixels above threshold
            n_true, n_pred = tf.reduce_sum(true), tf.reduce_sum(pred)
            # then I create a switch using tf.conditional
            switch = tf.cond(tf.logical_or(n_true < min_pix, n_pred < min_pix), lambda: tf.zeros_like(true), lambda: tf.ones_like(true))
            # this essentially allows me to turn off the loss if either condition is met
            # so I then run the function
            loss = get_loss(true, pred) # returns random constant if either is below threshold
            loss += tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(loss, switch))
        return loss
    return gen_loss
```

This may work, it compiles and trains a convolutional model. However, I don't like that there are random constants wandering about my loss function, and I'd rather only operate the function get_loss() if both true and pred meet the minimum conditions.

I'd prefer to make two tensors, one with samples not meeting the condition, the other with samples meeting the condition.

---

Separately, I've tried to use tf.conditional to test for each case and call a separate loss function in either case. The code is repeated below.

```
def avgMED(scaler, cutoff=20, min_N=30,c=3):
    def AVGmed(y_true, y_pred):
        const = tf.constant([c],tf.float32) # constant c, multiplied by MED (
        batch_size = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], tf.float32)
        MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred))
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(tf.shape(y_true)[0], -1))
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, shape=(tf.shape(y_pred)[0], -1))
        loss, loss_med = tf.cast(0,dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(0,dtype=tf.float32)
        # rescale
        y_true = y_true*scaler.scale_
        y_true = y_true+scaler.mean_
        y_pred = y_pred*scaler.scale_
        y_pred = y_pred+scaler.mean_
        trues = tf.map_fn(fn = lambda x: x, elems=y_true)
        preds = tf.map_fn(fn = lambda x: x, elems=y_pred)
        min_nonzero_pixels = tf.reduce_sum(tf.constant(min_N, dtype=tf.float32))
        for idx in tf.range(batch_size):
            idx = tf.cast(idx, tf.int32)
            true = trues[idx]
            pred = preds[idx]
            MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tfm.square(tfm.subtract(true,pred)))
            true = tf.where(true<cutoff,0.0,1.0)
            pred = tf.where(pred<cutoff,0.0,1.0)
            n_true = tf.reduce_sum(true)
            n_pred = tf.reduce_sum(pred)
            loss_TA = tf.cond(tf.logical_or(n_true < min_nonzero_pixels, n_pred < min_nonzero_pixels), get_zero(true,pred), get_MED(true,pred))
            loss_med += loss_TA.read(0)
            loss += loss_med + MSE # do we benefit from reducing across the batch dimension? we should be able to look at familiar batches and see the little increase due to the distance component
            tf.print(n_true,n_pred)
            tf.print(loss_med)
        return loss # this is essentially MSE given c ~ 0. Thus, this will show if there are some weird gradients flowing through that are preventing the model from learning
    return AVGmed 

def get_MED(A,B):
    # takes in binary tensors
    indices_A, indices_B = tf.where(A), tf.where(B)
    coordX_A_TA, coordY_A_TA = find_coord(indices_A) # finds x,y coordinates and returns tensor array
    coordX_B_TA, coordY_B_TA = find_coord(indices_B)
    mindists_AB_TA = find_min_distances(coordX_A_TA, coordY_A_TA, coordX_B_TA, coordY_B_TA)
    mindists_BA_TA = find_min_distances(coordX_B_TA, coordY_B_TA, coordX_A_TA, coordY_A_TA)
    # MED = mean error distance = 
    med_AB = tf.reduce_mean(mindists_AB_TA.read(0))
    med_BA = tf.reduce_mean(mindists_BA_TA.read(0))
    avg_med = tfm.divide(tfm.add(med_AB,med_BA),tf.constant(0.5))
    loss_TA = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    loss_TA.write(loss_TA.size(), avg_med)
    return loss_TA 

def get_zero(A,B):
    loss_TA = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    loss_TA.write(loss_TA.size(), 0)
    return loss_TA
```

However, with this framework I am now getting new errors about my generator not having enough data, which is absurd given the batch size I test with is 10 and 1 step_per_epoch on a train size of 100. Got a warning about not closing the TensorArray, which I expect happens whether the conditional is true or false. Inching closer to a solution but could use some guidance on how problematic my tensorflow logic is.